# Jinja2 template super functions not rendered with django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have two very simple templates like

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}hello{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

and details.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block content %}{{ super() }} world{% endblock %}
```

but when i render a view with details.html i get this error

```
Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'super()'
```

do i need some import somewere?

(templates are rendered properly until i use the super() function)

Comment: How have you configured Django to use Jinja?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Django 1.7 and earlier do not support Jinja natively. Unless you've done something to use Jinja, your templates should be in Django template language, and you can't use Jinja.

Django 1.8 will have [support for multiple template engines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines), and native support for Jinja2.

In Django template language, you can use `{{ block.super }}` to access the content of the block from the parent template.

Comment: Is Django's use of `block.super` just a legacy from before jinja2 had `super()`? I am converting a site from using FastAPI where I had been using `super()`, which I had to change to `block.super`. Where templates were used outside of the django framework, i.e. relying only on the jinja2 engine, it had to remain as `super()`. Using `super()` *with* django throws the `TemplateSyntaxError`, `Could not parse the remainder: '()' from 'super()'`

Comment: @John I wouldn’t describe it as a legacy. Django template language and jinja2 have similar but different syntax. One key difference is that Jinja2 uses `()` for function calls and Django template language does not. You can’t expect both engines to render the same template.

You can either rewrite the template for django template engine and use `block.super`, or configure Django to use jinja2 for this template.

Comment: @Alisdair that's good to know a common pattern of difference, thanks. What I like about the pure jinja2 solution is it avoids any Django ceremony. I guess I'll learn that in time. I'm managing to share a common ancestor template, which is enough for now.